# How can I make my Selenium test suite launch its Firefox instances in Xnest or Xephyr and pass?

Tags: firefox, testing, selenium, x11

My software is set up so that to run the test suite I do:

```
$ make selenium-test
```

Done this way, the suite passes without problem. However, it is distracting to have the Firefox instance show up on my desktop. Moreover, I've sometimes accidentally made some tests fail when I moved my mouse around. So, I'd like to run Firefox in Xnest or Xephyr so that it is separate from my other applications. What I do is:

```
$ Xnest :1 &
$ DISPLAY=:1 make selenium-test
```

When I do this and my test suite is set to run Chrome, there's no problem whatsoever. However, when I do it with Firefox, I run into these problems:

1. I can't click Firefox's menus. This is needed because I sometimes tell Selenium to leave the browser open if the test fails.
2. I can't type anything in Firefox. This is needed because some of my tests deal with typing text or selecting text.
3. A Selenium test suite that works perfectly with Chrome fails with Firefox, and there is no good explanation for it.

Because of the second point then my test suite fails whenever try to run it in Xnest or Xephyr.

I've checked the options I can pass to Xnest and Xephyr and saw nothing there that was helpful.

The versions involved are:

- Firefox 22 and 24.
- Selenium 2.35.0 and 2.37.2
- Xnest and Xephyr 1.14.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution for unclickable menus and mysterious test failures

The first and third problems can be fixed by running a windows manager in the Xnest or Xephyr instance. So for instance:

```
$ DISPLAY=:1 openbox &
```

Note that running a window manager will **not** fix issues that have to do with browser incompatibilities. However, I've had tests that switch among browser windows fail on Firefox if there is no window manager. (These tests ran absolutely **fine** with Chrome.)

### Solution for typing

The second problem is due to Firefox interacting with DBus. This quick-and-dirty script (let's call it `start-on-display`) illustrates how it can be fixed:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset GTK_IM_MODULE
unset QT4_IM_MODULE
unset CLUTTER_IM_MODULE
unset XMODIFIERS
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

display=$1
shift

export DISPLAY=$display
exec "$@"
```

This script can be used like this:

```
$ start-on-display :1 firefox
```

Or with a test suite:

```
$ start-on-display :1 make selenium-test
```

Although `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` is the only variable that one must absolutely unset to get typing to work in Firefox, it is also advisable to unset the other environment variables, which are associated with input methods. It helps with Chrome, for instance. Chrome will start and run without problem but if you need to type in it, you'll have to switch its input method to "None" before it responds. If you unset the input method variables before launching Chrome, then you won't have to switch its input method before typing.

### Other possibilities

To avoid the distraction and accidental interaction with the test browser, besides using Xnest or Xephyr, one could also do the following.

#### Request that the browser be mapped off-screen

I've not tested it and don't know whether the browser or Selenium will have a problem with this. If one wants to inspect an instance that is already running, something like `wmctrl` could be used to bring the browser back into viewable space.

#### Use another virtual desktop

(I consider moving to a different screen to be the same strategy under a different name.)

Move to a different virtual desktop, start the browser there, come back to the primary desktop. Having to do the back and forth manually is a pain.

Or perhaps have something able to automatically map the browser to another desktop? You'll have to distinguish the instances of the browser started for testing purposes from those you've probably already have running on your desktop. I've done this before by using client properties like `WM_NAME` and `WM_CLASS`. Not impossible, but this can get complicated quick.

### Additional Tips

- If you use a extremely minimalist window manager like aewm or fvwm, Chromedriver has trouble determining the position and size of Chrome. The solution is to use no window manager at all (but then Firefox's menu won't work) or use a more substantial manager. I've had good success with openbox.