# Python Selenium Specify Display in Django App

Tags: python, selenium, vnc

I have a Django app and one of the View functions calls a script that creates a Selenium Webdriver. The server is running CentOS with a head and VNC server is running.

The error I'm getting is ' Error: no display specified.' How can I correctly specify a display to use when launching this script? Do I need to use something like pyvirtualdisplay?

I've tried this in the Python script:

```
    import os
    os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':3'
```

:3 is the VNC display I want to launch the Firefox instance at.

I've also tried pyvirtualdisplay:

```
    from pyvirtualdisplay.xvnc import XvncDisplay
    display = XvncDisplay(rfbport='5903')
    display.start()
```

This leads to the same no display specified error.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything inherently wrong with what you've described there. Are you sure you set the `DISPLAY` variable early enough?

Comment: That looks like it was an issue. I was setting it below the import for the webdriver. However, now I'm getting, 'No protocol specified. Error cannot open display :3' Is there another variable I have to set to say it's vnc?

Comment: After Googling "No protocol specified", I'm thinking you may be having trouble with a dbus instance interfering with what you are trying to do. You could try unsetting the environment variable`DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`. (I've run into this problem [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879554/how-can-i-make-my-selenium-test-suite-launch-its-firefox-instances-in-xnest-or-x) myself.)

Comment: No luck unsetting that environment variable. Still the same protocol error.

Answer (score 0):

Using PyVirtualDisplay like I did in my question ended up working:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay.xvnc import XvncDisplay
display = XvncDisplay(rfbport='5903')
display.start()
```

However, I was setting the environment variable before this, which was messing it up.